# ARCore Unity Google Cardboard support

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard, arcore

I would like to run Google's [ARCore sample demos](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/tutorials/hello-ar-sample) using a Cardboard headset.

I've checked off 'Virtual Reality Supported' under the Android Player Settings and have included 'Cardboard' as the VR SDK.

The resulting images from the camera do become stereoscopic. However, everything is a bit distorted upon putting the phone into an actual headset. I'm using a Pixel 2 fwiw. I haven't seen anything mentioned about ARCore working with tandem with VR, but I don't see why splitting the camera into a stereoscopic view shouldn't work.

Any ideas on how to fix the distorted view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FOV (field of view) of the phone's camera is around 60 degrees (horizontal direction), The VR camera i think is around 90 degrees thus there will be stretching/distortion of the image. see https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/134 for more info

Comment: Thanks for that thread Jon. I read through it a few times and am starting to understand the problem and proposed fix. Do you have specifics on how exactly you made the issue better? What files you changed, etc..? Also, I'm seeing that my view in the headset looks fine when I close one eye. So maybe my issue is more related to ARCore using just one camera, and Cardboard expecting two (left and right eye)?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the distortion I was seeing was easily resolved by just scanning the QR code of my headset to pair my phone with it. The image is far better now. I'm still seeing the depth issues, but as you mentioned this is due to the FOV issues